# What does the Reflect object do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I saw a blank stub on MDN a while ago for the `Reflect` object in javascript but I can't for the life of me find anything on Google. Today I found this http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-reflect-object and it sounds similar to the Proxy object apart from the realm and loader functionality.

Basically, I don't know whether this page I found only explains how to implement Reflect or if I just can't understand its wording. Could someone please explain to me generally what the methods of `Reflect` do?

For instance, on the page I found says that calling `Reflect.apply ( target, thisArgument, argumentsList )`
will "Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of target with arguments thisArgument and args." but how is that any different than just calling `target.apply(thisArgument, argumentsList)`?

Update:

Thanks to @Blue, I found this page on the wiki
http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:reflect_api&s=reflect
which to the best of my knowledge says that the reflect object provides method versions of all the actions that can be trapped by proxies to make forwarding easier. But that seems a little weird to me since I don't see how it's entirely necessary. But it Seems to do a little more than that, particularly the par that says `double-lifting` but that points to the old proxy spec/

Comment: The spec says "The Reflect object is a single ordinary object.", to my understanding `Reflect` is just a container for `Realm` and `Loader` objects, but I don't know what the latter do either.

Comment: Thanks:), I seems from the page I linked to (don't know how legitimate it is) that each Realm is its own "context of java script" and a loader loads Realms like modules or something, based on the similarities between reflect and proxy and the fact that proxy sort of "overloads" built in functionality could `Reflect.Loader` and `Reflect.Realm` have something to with overloading module functionality?

Comment: Looks like it's a 'static class' (like JSON) with static methods: `isExtensible`, `ownKeys` etc. In ES 6, with actual classes, this is useful to find out more about a class (`target` in [16.1.2](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-reflect.construct) I think).

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect/wiki?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

**UPDATE 2015:**
As pointed out by [7th](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316617/7th)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34541097/), now that ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) has been finalized, more appropriate documentation is now available:

- [ES6 spec, Reflection](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reflection)
- [MDN Reflect (including details and examples to all of its methods)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect)

---

**Original answer (for (historic) understanding and extra examples)**:

The `Reflection proposal` seems to have progressed to the [Draft ECMAScript 6 Specification](https://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-reflection). This document currently outlines the `Reflect`-object's methods and only states the following about the `Reflect`-object itself:

> The Reflect object is a single ordinary object.
>
> The value of the [[Prototype]] internal slot of the Reflect object is the standard built-in Object prototype object (19.1.3).
>
> The Reflect object is not a function object. It does not have a [[Construct]] internal method; it is not possible to use the Reflect object as a constructor with the **new** operator. The Reflect object also does not have a [[Call]] internal method; it is not possible to invoke the Reflect object as a function.

However, there is a short explanation about it's purpose in [ES Harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:reflect_api&s=reflect):

> The “@reflect” module serves multiple purposes:
>
> - Now that we have modules, a “@reflect” module is a more natural place for many of the reflection methods previously defined on Object.    
>   For backwards-compatibility purposes, it is unlikely that the static methods on Object will disappear. However, new methods should likely be added to the “@reflect” module rather than to the Object constructor.
> - A natural home for proxies, avoiding the need for a global Proxy binding.
> - Most methods in this module map one-to-one onto Proxy traps. Proxy handlers need these methods to conveniently forward operations, as shown below.

So, the `Reflect` object provides a number of utility functions, many of which appear to overlap with ES5 methods defined on the global Object.

However, that doesn't really explain what existing problems this intends to solve or what functionality is added. I suspected this could be shimmed and indeed, the above harmony-spec links to a ['non-normative, approximate implementation of these methods'](https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect/).

Examining that code could give (further) idea's about it's use, but thankfully there is also a wiki that outlines **[a number of reasons why the Reflect object is useful](https://github.com/tvcutsem/harmony-reflect/wiki)**:
<sub>(I've copied (and formatted) the following text for future reference from that source as they are the *only* examples I could find. Besides that, they make sense, already have a good explanation and touch the question's `apply` example.)</sub>

**More useful return values**

Many operations in `Reflect` are similar to ES5 operations defined on `Object`, such as `Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and `Reflect.defineProperty`. However, whereas `Object.defineProperty(obj, name, desc)` will either return `obj` when the property was successfully defined, or throw a `TypeError` otherwise, `Reflect.defineProperty(obj, name, desc)` is specced to simply return a boolean that indicates whether or not the property was successfully defined. This allows you to refactor this code:

```js
try {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, name, desc);
  // property defined successfully
} catch (e) {
  // possible failure (and might accidentally catch the wrong exception)
}
```

To this:

```js
if (Reflect.defineProperty(obj, name, desc)) {
  // success
} else {
  // failure
}
```

Other methods that return such a boolean success status are `Reflect.set` (to update a property), `Reflect.deleteProperty` (to delete a property), `Reflect.preventExtensions` (to make an object non-extensible) and `Reflect.setPrototypeOf` (to update an object's prototype link).

**First-class operations**

In ES5, the way to detect whether an object `obj` defines or inherits a certain property name is to write `(name in obj)`. Similarly, to delete a property, one uses `delete obj[name]`. While dedicated syntax is nice and short, it also means you must explicitly wrap these operations in functions when you want to pass the operation around as a first-class value.

With `Reflect`, these operations are readily defined as first-class functions:
`Reflect.has(obj, name)` is the functional equivalent of `(name in obj)` and `Reflect.deleteProperty(obj, name)` is a function that does the same as `delete obj[name].`

**More reliable function application**

In ES5, when one wants to call a function `f` with a variable number of arguments packed as an array `args` and binding the `this` value to `obj`, one can write:

```js
f.apply(obj, args)
```

However, `f` could be an object that intentionally or unintentionally defines its own `apply` method. When you really want to make sure that the built-in `apply` function is called, one typically writes:

```js
Function.prototype.apply.call(f, obj, args)
```

Not only is this verbose, it quickly becomes hard to understand. With `Reflect`, you can now make a reliable function call in a shorter and easier to understand way:

```js
Reflect.apply(f, obj, args)
```

**Variable-argument constructors**

Imagine you want to call a constructor function with a variable number of arguments. In ES6, thanks to the new spread syntax, it will be possible to write code like:

```js
var obj = new F(...args)
```

In ES5, this is harder to write, because one can only use `F.apply` or `F.call` to call a function with a variable number of arguments, but there is no `F.construct` function to `new` the function with a variable number of arguments. With `Reflect`, one can now write, in ES5:

```js
var obj = Reflect.construct(F, args)
```

**Default forwarding behavior for Proxy traps**

When using `Proxy` objects to wrap existing objects, it is very common to intercept an operation, do something, and then to "do the default thing", which is typically to apply the intercepted operation to the wrapped object. For example, say I want to simply log all property accesses to an object `obj`:

```js
var loggedObj = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: function(target, name) {
    console.log("get", target, name);
    // now do the default thing
  }
});
```

The `Reflect` and `Proxy` APIs *were designed in tandem*, such that for each `Proxy` trap, there exists a corresponding method on `Reflect` that "does the default thing". Hence, whenever you find yourself wanting to "do the default" thing inside a Proxy handler, the correct thing to do is to always call the corresponding method in the `Reflect` object:

```js
var loggedObj = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: function(target, name) {
    console.log("get", target, name);
    return Reflect.get(target, name);
  }
});
```

The return type of the `Reflect` methods is guaranteed to be compatible with the return type of the `Proxy` traps.

**Control the this-binding of accessors**

In ES5 it's fairly easy to do a generic property access or property update. For instance:

```js
var name = ... // get property name as a string
obj[name] // generic property lookup
obj[name] = value // generic property update
```

The `Reflect.get` and `Reflect.set` methods allow you to do the same thing, but additionally accept as a last optional argument a `receiver` parameter that allows you to explicitly set the `this`-binding when the property that you get/set is an accessor:

```js
var name = ... // get property name as a string
Reflect.get(obj, name, wrapper) // if obj[name] is an accessor, it gets run with `this === wrapper`
Reflect.set(obj, name, value, wrapper)
```

This is occasionally useful when you're wrapping `obj` and you want any self-sends within the accessor to get re-routed to your wrapper, e.g. if `obj` is defined as:

```js
var obj = {
  get foo() { return this.bar(); },
  bar: function() { ... }
}
```

Calling `Reflect.get(obj, "foo", wrapper)` will cause the `this.bar()` call to get rerouted to `wrapper`.

**Avoid legacy `__proto__`**

On some browsers, `__proto__` is defined as a special property that gives access to an object's prototype. ES5 standardized a new method `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` to query the prototype. `Reflect.getPrototypeOf(obj)` does exactly the same, except that `Reflect` also defines a corresponding `Reflect.setPrototypeOf(obj, newProto)` to set the object's prototype. This is the new ES6-compliant way of updating an object's prototype.
Note that: [`setPrototypeOf` **also** exists on `Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) (as correctly pointed out by [Knu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248058/knu)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421903/what-does-the-reflect-object-do-in-javascript#comment50566428_25585988))!

---

**EDIT:**
Side-note (addressing comments to the Q): There is a short and simple [answer on 'Q: ES6 Modules vs. HTML Imports'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22483249/588079) that explains `Realms` and `Loader` objects.

Another explanation is offered by [this link](https://gist.github.com/dherman/7568885):

> A realm object abstracts the notion of a distinct global environment,
> with its own global object, copy of the standard library, and
> "intrinsics" (standard objects that are not bound to global variables,
> like the initial value of Object.prototype).
>
> *Extensible web*: This is the dynamic equivalent of a same-origin
> `<iframe>` without DOM.

Worth mentioning though: <s>all this is still in draft, this is not a specification etched in stone!</s> It's ES6, so keep browser-compatibility in mind!

Comment: @Spencer Killen: Well.. did this answer point your thoughts in the right direction and explain how this relates to the difference between `Reflect.apply` and `target.apply`? Or what should I add before the bounty ends?

Comment: [setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/setPrototypeOf) also exists on `Object`.

Comment: Note that using `Reflect.get` as the default implementation for proxy get doesn't work nicely if you are proxying an object with prototype properties. It just complains that it doesn't work. However if you instead use `Reflect.get(target, property)` without passing the `receiver`, then it does work.

Comment: My tests where you always access properties through the proxy, results in a situation where the `target` is the original target that the proxy wraps, while `receiver` is the proxy itself. But again this could be different if you manage to access the properties differently.

Answer (score 5):

Going by the draft document found on the wiki,

http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts

We get the line about "single ordinary object" which it clarifies in the draft. It also has the function definitions.

The wiki should be reliable since you can find a link to it from the emcascript website

http://www.ecmascript.org/dev.php

I found the first link by google though and didn't have any luck finding it by searching the wiki directly.

Comment: Thanks, the steps taken when each method is called listed in the official spec seem pretty much they same as the ones in my link but I still can't figure out what each method does when it's called, for instance under Reflect. Apply the steps are listed 4. Perform the PrepareForTailCall abstract operation.
5. Return the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of target with arguments thisArgument and args -------what does that mean?

Comment: My best guess from looking at it is that it is referencing tail recursion in step 4 and step 5 is a reference to the prototype function. It looks like the general idea is to verify the apply method can run on what its applied to (steps 1-2), error handle (step 3) and then invoke the function apply is being run against (steps 4-5). My best guess from scanning through the documentation is that the point of the Reflect module is when your doing functionality that requires some form of introspection of the object. The use of call is also probably why it "does not have a [[Call]] internal method".

Answer (score -1):

The design goal of Reflect is to:

1. **Improving the readability and maintainability of code.**
2. **Helping to avoid common errors and vulnerabilities**. For example, using Reflect to call a function can avoid some of the errors that can occur when using the call() or apply() methods.

Comment: Do you have any sources for these claims?