# Is there any benefit to call Reflect.apply() over Function.prototype.apply() in ECMAScript 2015?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I am just wondering if there is any good reason to call:

```
Reflect.apply(myFunction, myObject, args);
```

instead of:

```
myFunction.apply(myObject, args);
```

Comment: Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/apply), "less verbose and easier to understand".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can compare the definition of [`Function.prototype.apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.apply) and [`Reflect.apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-reflect.apply) in the spec.

Basically they are equivalent, but there is a difference: if the arguments list is `null` or `undefined`, `Function.prototype.apply` will call the function with no arguments, and `Reflect.apply` will throw.

```
function func() {
  return arguments.length;
}
func.apply(void 0, null); // 0
Reflect.apply(func, void 0, null); // TypeError: null is not a non-null object
```

Another difference is that, when you use `func.apply`, you assume

- `func` is a `Function` instance, i.e. it inherits from `Function.prototype`
- `func` has no `apply` own property which would shadow `Function.prototype.apply`

But `Reflect.apply` doesn't require that. For example,

```js
var obj = document.createElement('object');
typeof obj; // "function" -- can be called
obj.apply; // undefined -- does not inherit from Function.prototype
Reflect.apply(obj, thisArg, argList); // -- works properly
```

```js
var func = a => a;
func.apply = a => 0;
func.apply(void 0, [123]); // 0 -- Function.prototype.apply is shadowed by an own property
Reflect.apply(func, void 0, [123]); // 123 -- works properly
```

Comment: The second difference can easily be overcome through `Function.prototype.apply.call`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum But that's longer. And assumes that no mad script stopped `Function.prototype.apply` from inheriting from `Function.prototype` nor added a custom `call` own method.

Comment: If you override `Function.prototype.apply` in your own code may god have mercy on your soul.

Comment: Is it necessary to pass in `void 0` as parameter or it is equivalent as `undefined`?

Comment: @Thomson `undefined` might be shadowed by a local variable with another value. `void 0` always returns the original undefined value.

Comment: If  `apply` is shadowed for some function it's probably done for a reason - logging, mocking, etc. Using `Reflect.apply()` would bypass all that.

Comment: @Oriol not in strict mode.

Comment: @stephband — Strict mode prevents the global object’s property 'undefined' from being overwritten. It doesn’t prevent non-global scopes from declaring their own variables named 'undefined'. (Not suggesting people should worry about it — just clarifying what exactly strict mode changed in this regard.)

Comment: Correction: It isn’t strict mode that influences that behavior, it was a general change made in ES5 (I scratched my head a bit after I wrote that, since it made no sense that a mode could alter how some specific descriptor was read.) In other words, strict mode isn’t really a factor at all in the behavior of the undefined binding.

Answer (score 11):

See also the SO question [What does the Reflect object do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421903/what-does-the-reflect-object-do-in-javascript), which includes this text in the top answer:

> Now that we have modules, a “@reflect” module is a more natural place for many of the reflection methods previously defined on Object. For backwards-compatibility purposes, it is unlikely that the static methods on Object will disappear. However, new methods should likely be added to the “@reflect” module rather than to the Object constructor

My understanding is that in previous iterations of JS, tools related to "reflection" have been scattered around the language, as part of the Object prototype and Function prototype. The `Reflect` object is an effort to bring them under one roof.

So, in the case of your question, although there are differences (see Oriol's answer), the reason for both to exist is a general move to future-proof reflection tooling in the ES spec.

Comment: This is the only explanation that convinced me

Answer (score -1):

One use i can think of is using Reflect.apply in flow managment or in functions that execute an array of function

```
function execFuncs(funcArr){
 var obj = this.someObj;
 funcArr.forEach(function(func){
    Reflect.apply(func,obj)
 });
}
```

which much more convinient then

```
function execFuncs(funcArray){
  var obj = this.someObj;
  funcArray.forEach(function(func){
      func.prototype.apply(obj)
  })
}
```

since you have more control.