# Why should I call Function.prototype.apply.call(x, ...) instead of x.apply(...)?

Tags: javascript, apply

[The doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/apply#Description) of `Reflect.apply()` on MDN web docs states:

> In ES5, you typically use the Function.prototype.apply() method to
>   call a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an
>   array (or an array-like object).
>   `Function.prototype.apply.call(Math.floor, undefined, [1.75]);`
>
> With `Reflect.apply` this becomes less verbose and easier to understand.

I'm confused. In ES5, I typically use (to keep the example above):

`Math.floor.call(undefined, [1.75]);`

Why should somebody use instead:

`Function.prototype.apply.call(Math.floor, undefined, [1.75]);`

---

P.S.: My question is not about `Reflect.apply(myFunction, myObject, args);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any benefit to call Reflect.apply() over Function.prototype.apply() in ECMAScript 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707306/is-there-any-benefit-to-call-reflect-apply-over-function-prototype-apply-in)

Comment: @LeroyStav - Similar, but definitely different, that's comparing `Function.prototype.appy` and `Reflect.apply`, the above asks about `Function.prototype.apply` vs. `someFunction.apply`. (I wouldn't be surprised if there is a direct dupetarget, though...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and yet the accepted answer does cover that specific sub-question so-to-speak.  Getting more background information is always valuable when it comes to questions like this.  So yes, you are strictly correct in that the questions are not identical, but it seems to me like the accepted answer to the "possible duplicate" question covers all the bases, no?

Comment: @LeroyStav - If it did, it would, yes; SO doesn't require the questions to be exactly the same as long as the other question's answers answer this question. To my mind, none of the answers there really clearly answers this question. Oriol's mentions something in passing briefly about shadowed properties, but that's about it. Anyway, if a consensus goes the other way, I won't argue against it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'll accept any mod removal :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to override the methods on a function, making `apply` do something other than its default purpose:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("This doesn't happen");
}
foo.apply = function() {
  console.log("This happens instead.");
};

foo.apply({});
```

Also, back in the old days host-provided functions didn't always have those methods (but that's mostly not true anymore).

It's similar to the reason that people recommend using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, y)` [or the new `Object.hasOwn(x, y)`] rather than `x.hasOwnProperty(y)`. (But in that case, it also protects against the possibility that `x` doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`, which is possible now. For instance, if `x` is the result of `Object.create(null)` or inherits from any object created that way.)

Comment: That's right but as `apply` is a configurable and writable property of `Function.prototype`, it's also possible to override `Function.prototype.apply` making it do something other than its default purpose.  (The same applies to `Reflect.apply`.) So, regarding this point, there is no real difference.

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet - There's a difference: Mucking about with `Function.prototype.apply` will break a **lot** of things. Mucking about with `apply` on specific functions only breaks `apply` on those specific functions. (And then there's the host-provided function thing, largely historic now.)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. It only seems to be a question which of the both tamperings in my environment is the more likely one. But still both are possible. Just tried both in node .js REPL and my system hasn't exploded in either case. ;-)

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet - I meant as soon as you start using some modules that aren't your own or part of the standard lib. :-)